# Send javascript to console with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, bots

I'm trying to send a command to the JavaScript console with Selenium, but it keeps returning `None`

```
    driver.execute_script('ScavengeScreen')
```

If I enter 'ScavengeScreen' into the Firefox console I get an object back.

[image: firefox console]

More info of the 'ScavengeScreen' JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        Timing.whenReady(function() {
            require(['Modules/ScavengeScreen/ScavengeScreen'], function(ScavengeScreen) {
                var data = {...some json data...};

                if (window.hasOwnProperty('ScavengingOverview') && window.ScavengingOverview.data_data.hasOwnProperty(data.data_id)) {
                    data = window.ScavengingOverview.data_data[data.data_id];
                }

                var screen = new ScavengeScreen(...some json data...);
                screen.init();
                window.ScavengeScreen = screen;
                screen.updateInputs();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I get the same result in Selenium?

Comment: can you link me the site please?

Comment: try adding `return` as the first script statement so that the line would be `driver.execute_script('return ScavengeScreen;')`

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw I'm sorry but the site is behind a paywall. But I can post more info if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `driver.execute_script('ScavengeScreen')` to `driver.execute_script('return ScavengeScreen;')`.